# show size of existing vm size in azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How can you find the size of an existing VM using the Azure CLI? I can see how to find what sizes are available, or what sizes a VM can be resized to, but not simply what the existing size is. You'd think that might be one of the details in `az vm show --show-details` but it's not.

Comment: Per my test, the `vmSize` is existing, https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZrDu.png is it you want?

Comment: Ahh I was using `--output table` - didn't realise that restricted what was shown. Thanks for the test, happy to give the points if you want to make it an answer!

Comment: Yeah, you can also use `--query 'hardwareProfile.vmSize'` to get it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot in my comment, I use the command.

```
az vm show -g '<resource group name>' -n '<VM name>' -d
```

You could use `--query 'hardwareProfile.vmSize'` to get the `vmSize` directly.

```
az vm show -g '<resource group name>' -n '<VM name>' --query 'hardwareProfile.vmSize' -o tsv
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just as additional info, when using

```
az vm show -g <resourcegroupname> -n <vmname>
```

you can see which info is available to access.

For the VMSize you would notice in the responsetree:
**JSONResponse**

[image]

Which you can then access by using the query posted by Joy Wang.